# javascript regex replace html chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using JavaScript to set the value of an input with text that may contain HTML specific chars such a `&amp;` `&nbsp;` etc.  So, I'm trying to find one regex that will match these values and replace them with the appropriate value ("&", " ") respectively, only I can't figure out the regex to do it.

Here's my attempt:

Make an object that contains the matches and reference to the replacement value:

```
var specialChars = {
  "&amp;nbsp;" : " ",
  "&amp;amp;"  : "&",
  "&amp;gt;"   : ">",
  "&amp;lt;"   : "<"
}
```

Then, I want to match my string

```
var stringToMatch = "This string has special chars &amp;amp; and &amp;nbsp;"
```

I tried something like

```
stringToMatch.replace(/(&amp;nbsp;|&amp;)/g,specialChars["$1"]);
```

but it doesn't work.  I don't really understand how to capture the special tag and replace it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps "&amp;nbsp;" will show your &nbsp;?

Comment: Why not use escaping? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: escape would turn &amp; into %26amp%3B.  Definitely not what I"m looking for

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can use the functions from a question on a slightly different subject ([Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921)).

Jason Bunting's answer has some nice ideas + the necessary explanation, here is his solution with some modifications to get you started (*if you find this helpful, upvote his original answer as well, as this is his code, essentially*).

```
var replaceHtmlEntites = (function() {
    var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g,
        translate = {
            'nbsp': String.fromCharCode(160), 
            'amp' : '&', 
            'quot': '"',
            'lt'  : '<', 
            'gt'  : '>'
        },
        translator = function($0, $1) { 
            return translate[$1]; 
        };

    return function(s) {
        return s.replace(translate_re, translator);
    };
})();
```

callable as

```
var stringToMatch = "This string has special chars &amp; and &amp;nbsp;";
var stringOutput  = replaceHtmlEntites(stringToMatch);
```

Numbered entites are even easier, you can replace them much more generically using a little math and [`String.fromCharCode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp).

---

Another, much simpler possibility would be like this (works in any browser)

```
function replaceHtmlEntites(string) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = string;
    return div.textContent || div.innerText;
}

replaceHtmlEntites("This string has special chars &lt; &amp; &gt;");
// -> "This string has special chars < & >"
```

Comment: So apparently I don't understand regex's.  Your code looked pretty good to me, but the value (s) being passed into the function actually contains the whole &nbsp;  Not just the nbsp.  I thought the brackets were supposed to match just the inside chars?  Anyway, modding that translate object to contain the whole "&nbsp;", "&amp;" etc. worked. otherwise it just returned undefined.  Thanks

Comment: The answer has been modified a little bit to accommodate for this. I guess you've tried with the original code. The above works for me, I've just tried it out (again).

Comment: Really?  No I copied your code and ran it through the debugger, the value for me being passed in (s) was the whole &nbsp;.  Very odd.  I'm using safari and I tested in Firefox.  I'll try a few other browsers too.  ANyway thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the changes.  The extra entity attr in the return function.  Thx again!!

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be creating a div object

```
var tmp = document.createElement("div");
```

Then assigning the text to its innerHTML

```
tmp.innerHTML = mySpecialString;
```

And finally reading the element's text content

```
var output = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText //for IE compatibility
```

And there you go...

Comment: I'm using the text to set a value of an input (w/ jquery) so $(input).val(someText)  it's the someText that needs the replacement

Comment: Okay I got the point. When you do what I have suggested, all the values are converted by the HTML engine of the browser since the "textContent" or "innerText" property contains the "resultant text".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function based replacement to do what you want to do:

```
var myString = '&'+'nbsp;&'+'nbsp;&tab;&copy;';
myString.replace(/&\w+?;/g, function( e ) {
    switch(e) {
        case '&nbsp;': 
            return ' ';
        case '&tab;': 
            return '\t';
        case '&copy;': 
            return String.fromCharCode(169);
        default: 
            return e;
    }
});
```

However, I do urge you to consider your situation. If you're receiving &nbsp; and &copy; and other HTML entities in your text values, do you really want to replace them? Should you be converting them afterwards?

Just something to keep in mind.

Cheers!

Comment: This is way more straightforward than the above accepted answer.  Also, I believe it will scale better as more entities are added to the list, which is important since the list of named entities is SUPER long.  You got robbed son!

Comment: I'm not in it for the points. I'm in it for the questions. But thanks for the sentiment. :)  There's also the fact that the default case should be return e; not wrapping. Fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

A modern variation that doesn't use painful switch/case statements:

```
const toEscape = `<code> 'x' & "y" </code> <\code>`

toEscape.replace(
  /[&"'<>]/g,
  (char) => ({
      "&": '&amp;',
      "\"": '&quot;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      "<": '&lt;',
      ">": '&gt;',
    })[char]
)
```

Or, since this really should be turned into a function:

```
const encodeHTML = function(str) {
    const charsToEncode = /[&"'<>]/g
    const encodeTo = {
      "&": '&amp;',
      "\"": '&quot;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      "<": '&lt;',
      ">": '&gt;',
    }
    return str.replace(charsToEncode, char => encodeTo[char])
}
```

(This list of characters is chosen based on the [list of XML-escape-char-codes available on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).)

Answer (score 0):

a more better approach for replace any HTML tags & HTML special characters would be to just replace these with REGEX

```
str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```