# Convert HTML Entities using JavaScript (RegExp)

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote following code:

```
function convert(string) {
  var before = '&';
  var after= '&amp;'; 
  var pattern = new RegExp(before, 'g');
  return string.replace(pattern,after);
}
convert("Dolce & Gabbana");
```

And it works just fine - returns `Dolce &amp; Gabbana`.
How could I do this through some loop, for multiple patterns, like this:

```
var multiple = {
    '&' : '&amp;',
    '<' : '&lt;',
    '>' : '&gt;',
    '"' : '&quot;',
    '`' : '&apos;'
  };
```

Comment: You can read this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229518/javascript-regex-replace-html-chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229518/javascript-regex-replace-html-chars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over your multiple-object, like so:

```
    function convert(string) {
       var multiple = {
        '&' : '&amp;',
        '<' : '&lt;',
        '>' : '&gt;',
        '"' : '&quot;',
        '`' : '&apos;'
      };
      for(var char in multiple) {
        var before = char;
        var after= multiple[char]; 
        var pattern = new RegExp(before, 'g');
        string = string.replace(pattern,after);    
      }
      return string;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!