# Jquery Table sorter and special characters

Tags: jquery, character, tablesorter, diacritics

am using jquery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin and in my "country" column i got special characters like this: Índia.

The fact is that when i hit the header of the column to sort it, it puts my "Índia" at the end of the column. I guess the nav sees the Í instead of the real "I" with an accent.

Any clue on how to make it work even with accents ?

Here's the js code in my domready:

```
$.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra'];
$.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = [[0,0]];
$("table").tablesorter();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at A List Apart's article on accent folding? They suggest using an array to map certain accented characters to their associated non-accent characters in order to help with the example's auto-complete feature. 

Here's a link: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accent-folding-for-auto-complete/

I hope this helps point you in the right direction. I'll take a closer look at that plugins code and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i gave a look but i have to admit it doesnt help me much. Am not a jquery dev so i'm a bit lost...

Comment: With the special characters in your data, can they be safely removed from the data and replaced with a normal character? Or do you need to keep the accents and such intact?

Comment: Yeah i could but it's a spelling mistake. So i'd like to keep the accent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This person had the same problem you did. Check this question out: [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for the link Levi, it's that. The only thing is that it doesnt work. I already double checked but cant see where the pb is.

Comment: If someone's having the some trouble, just follow the link Levi gave and read my chat with Tomalak at the bottom of the page, works for me now.