# Replace a list of emoticons with their images

Tags: javascript, emoticons

I have an array with:

```
emoticons = {
   ':-)' : 'smile1.gif',
   ':)'  : 'smile2.gif',
   ':D'  : 'smile3.gif'     
}
```

then i have a variabile with the text.

```
var text = 'this is a simple test :)';
```

and a variable with the url of the website

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/";
```

How to write a function that replace the symbols with their images?

The `<img>` tag result should be:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/simple2.gif" />
```

(I have to concatenate the url varible to the name of the image).

THank you very much!

Answer (score 33):

Another approach:

```
function replaceEmoticons(text) {
  var emoticons = {
    ':-)' : 'smile1.gif',
    ':)'  : 'smile2.gif',
    ':D'  : 'smile3.gif'
  }, url = "http://www.domain.com/";
  // a simple regex to match the characters used in the emoticons
  return text.replace(/[:\-)D]+/g, function (match) {
    return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img src="'+url+emoticons[match]+'"/>' :
           match;
  });
}

replaceEmoticons('this is a simple test :)');
// "this is a simple test <img src="http://www.domain.com/smile2.gif"/>"
```

**Edit:** [@pepkin88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409149/pepkin88) made a really good suggestion, build the regular expression based on the property names of the `emoticons` object.

It can be easily done, but we have to escape meta-characters if we want this to work properly.

The escaped patterns are stored on an array, that is later used to build the regular expression using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/User:Potappo/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp_(constructor)) constructor, by basically joining all the patterns separated with the `|` metacharacter.

```
function replaceEmoticons(text) {
  var emoticons = {
    ':-)' : 'smile1.gif',
    ':)'  : 'smile2.gif',
    ':D'  : 'smile3.gif',
    ':-|'  : 'smile4.gif'
  }, url = "http://www.domain.com/", patterns = [],
     metachars = /[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g;

  // build a regex pattern for each defined property
  for (var i in emoticons) {
    if (emoticons.hasOwnProperty(i)){ // escape metacharacters
      patterns.push('('+i.replace(metachars, "\\$&")+')');
    }
  }

  // build the regular expression and replace
  return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'),'g'), function (match) {
    return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img src="'+url+emoticons[match]+'"/>' :
           match;
  });
}

replaceEmoticons('this is a simple test :-) :-| :D :)');
```

Comment: It would be even better if regexp was generated depending on keys values in `emoticons`.

Comment: @pepkin88: Great suggestion :), I've added a function that makes this possible.

Comment: This could be further enhanced by closing over the `replace()` (similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string/614397#614397)…) - this would accelerate repeated calls to the function.

Comment: @CMS It was great help for one of my applications.

Comment: Awesome answer! Especially the second part :) The first one matches all kind of symbols (like ':', ')' and even 'D'), which I think will be very slow in large amount of text. The second one is great, with a little modification, that @Tomalak suggested - it's not worth to create all patterns every time. Anyways - still great answer! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
for ( smile in emoticons )
{
   text = text.replace(smile, '<img src="' + url + emoticons[smile] + '" />');
}
```

Comment: It won't work correctly since replace replaces only the first ocurrence of the matched string.

Comment: Only works to replace the first occurance of each smiley. In a string like "This is replaced :) but not this :)" the second one is left unchanged.

Comment: Also make sure to use `var` in the `for...in` statement, otherwise if the code is inside a function that doesn't declare the `smile` variable in that scope, it will become global, and using an `if (emoticons.hasOwnProperty(smile))` inside the loop is a good idea.

Comment: ok, so how to use .replace() to replace more then one occurence ?

Comment: to replace more than one occurrence change `smile` to `new RegExp(smile, 'g')`

Comment: or you can also /smile/g :P

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex with an array of find replace elements works well.

```
var emotes = [
    [':\\\)', 'happy.png'],
    [':\\\(', 'sad.png']
];

function applyEmotesFormat(body){
    for(var i = 0; i < emotes.length; i++){
        body = body.replace(new RegExp(emotes[i][0], 'gi'), '<img src="emotes/' + emotes[i][1] + '">');
    }
    return body;
}
```