# Regex preg_replace for emoticons

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace a list of emoticons with their images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055515/replace-a-list-of-emoticons-with-their-images)

i'm developing a website where i want to give users possibility to put smiles on posts.
My (just functional) idea is to use array in this way:

```
$emoticons = array(
array("17.gif",":)"),
array("6.jpg",":P"),
.....
array("9.jpg",":'("),
array("5.gif","X)")
);
```

with image on [0] and emoticon on [1].
And on each $post:

```
foreach($emoticons as $emoticon){
     $quoted_emoticon = preg_quote($emoticon[1],"#");
     $match = '#(?!<\w)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?!\w)#';
     $post = preg_replace($match,'<img src="images/emoticons/'.$emoticon[0].'">',$post);
}
```

This is working good, but my problem is `'#(?!<\w)('` and `')(?!\w)#'` because I want emoticons to apply only when preceding characters are "begin" (`^`) or "blank" and succeeding characters are "end" (`$`) or "blank". What is the right regex to do this?

Comment: You want emoticons to only be replaced at the beginning or ending of your string?

Comment: No, everywhere... even on the beginning or ending... exactly as anyother forum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the positive look behind and positive look ahead.

Example:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\:\))(?=\s|$)
```

Your example updated:

```
foreach($emoticons as $emoticon){
     $quoted_emoticon = preg_quote($emoticon[1],"#");
     $match = '(?<=\s|^)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?=\s|$)';
     $post = preg_replace($match,'<img src="images/emoticons/'.$emoticon[0].'">',$post);
}
```

Comment: Better... but not perfect, because the first occurance does not work. At the begin, if the $post is only :) it does not work!

Comment: I changed in this way:
$match = '#(?<=\s|$)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?=\s|$)#';

Comment: infact it's this:
$match = '#(?<=\s|^)(' . $quoted_emoticon .')(?=\s|$)#';

Comment: Sorry, a lazy copy paste error. I updated my expression.

Comment: @GiuseppeDonato - This answer works for you? Look at http://ideone.com/vhBar - Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you could use `(?<!\b)`...`(?!\b)` as a shorter equivalent, if you want to.

Comment: @user1215106, no I didn't test the code, I added it to the OP's example so he could see the difference. I'm sure the OP can figure out any syntax issues. My expression, however, fits the OP's needs "exactly".

Comment: @used2could - it is not about syntax, but about not escaping content of emotion string - it does not work - test it.

Comment: @user1215106, The pattern I listed works http://regexr.com?31c2u, I don't care about the modified PHP snippet fully working. It was only written for a little more context of the positive look behind and ahead in his work. Like I said, the OP can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
$e = array( ':)' => '1.gif',
            ':(' => '2.gif',
          );

foreach ($e as $sign => $file) { 
  $sign = preg_replace('/(.)/', "\\$1", $sign); 
  $pattern = "/(?<=\s|^)$sign(?=\s|$)/";
  $post = preg_replace($pattern, " <img src=\"images/emoticons/$file\">", $post);  
}
```

Comment: No, you didn't understand or i was not able to explain the problem:
I want to apply replace ONLY when preceding/succeeding char is BLANK (or they are ^|$, that means begin/end)
My data structure already work! I have no problem replacing... i want to limit WHEN to replace!

Comment: if someone write:
  Hello, my name is Ralph ;-)
OK. If some write:
  Hello, my name is Ralph;-)
NO
Understand?