# Create a text input that changes smileys code to picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page i have a text input field and I want that when user writes code of a smileys (like :D) inside that field, input field changes that code to picture.

How can i do it?

Comment: This question might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form

Comment: @charliefortune: no, i want when i write code of smileys inside that field, input field changes that code to picture.

Comment: I know, but the css background-image property might be the way to go with this. Also, in your question, you should let us know what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across this query earlier too. There is a chain going about the same query.

**It doesnot look as easy as you are trying to potray. Writing and converting does not make sense at all.**

APPROACH: You have to read each and every text entered by user if it matches the pattern of the smile and if the smiley matches then fetch the respective .gif from the images folder.

Please refer following link for a quick start.

[Replace a list of emoticons with their images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055515/replace-a-list-of-emoticons-with-their-images)

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be quite late, but this question still ranks high on Google...

The easiest way to add this feature ist to Use the [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) plugin (MIT licence). This is a JavaScript-and-CSS solution that pimps any textarea into a WYSIWYG editor. If the toolbar is disabled (see http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/options/), you result in a text input that automatically replaces emoticons with corresponding images.

Hint: It may be necessary to tell the script where to find the emoticons, using the `emoticonsRoot` option (took me 10 minutes to find that out - 10 of 30 minutes required from finding the SCEditor to making it work...).