# Replace x, y and z to w, u, and i in one replace

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm not so good at javascript and it's replace, so I'm wondering if you can optimize this line (etc one .replace instead of two):

```
$itemClicked.replace(/ä|å/g, 'a').replace(/ö/g, 'o');
```

Comment: Why do you need to *optimize* this line? Is it a performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the best possible if you only need to replace just these 3 letters. Using 1 `.replace` is possible, but it must use a function, e.g.

```
$itemClicked.replace(/[äåö]/g, function(s) { return s=='ö'?'o':'a'; });
```

See [*JavaScript: Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string) for a generalization.