# javascript sort with unicode

Tags: javascript, sorting

There are a lot of examples for sorting some JSON array by some property (i.e. 'title')
We are using compare function like this one:

```
function sortComparer(a, b) {
        if (a.title == b.title)
            return 0;
        return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Problem is that Serbian Latin alphabet order looks like "A, B, C, Č, Ć, D,..."
When using sortComparer above I am getting D sorted before "Č" or "Ć".
Any idea how to sort respecting current culture language?

Comment: One way would be to replace the other characters with their ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Not sure what you think. Only way I am getting on my mind is to define array of letters like: var letters = {'a','b','c', 'č','ć', ...} and in sortComparer function compare indexes. Disadvantage of this approach is that we have to write such array for each culture that is not english.

Comment: Javascript does not support the Unicode Collation Algorithm, so you’re basically hosed.  You cannot use a code point sort and get anything reasonable. To get an alphabetical sort, you need the UCA.

Comment: I think your expected order is wrong. There is an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator#using_options

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If the locale in your system is set correctly then you can use `localeCompare` method instead of *greater-than* operator to compare the strings - this method is locale aware.

```
function sortComparer(a,b){
    return a.title.localeCompare(b.title)
};
```

Comment: This will work only if locale is set. Any method to pass culture together with compared value?

Comment: There's no way to set the locale by script, it is defined by the browser or - depending from the browser - inherited from the OS.

Comment: I have found full solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630645/how-to-compare-utf-8-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Be aware that the `localeCompare` function is a lot heavier to run than just comparing strings using `<`, `>`, and `=` operators. Even starting at a result set of 500, there's a significant slow-down using `localeCompare`. As illustrated here, it is slower by a factor of up to 400: https://jsfiddle.net/L4715qey/

Comment: how about desc sorting?

Comment: Returned value is a number, so to reverse ordering use - sign.

Answer (score 5):

For sorting an array with a custom setting do as following:

1. Create an array with a custom order of alphabets:

   `var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "Č", "Ć", "D","Dž","Đ","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","Lj","M","N","Nj","O","P","R","S", "ÛŒ","T","U","V","Z","Ž"];`
2. Create a list of test array:

   `var testArrray = ["B2","D6","A1","Ć5","Č4","C3"];`
3. Create a sort function name:

   ```
   function OrderFunc(){
             testArrray.sort(function (a, b) {
                 return CharCompare(a, b, 0);
             });
         }
   ```
4. create the CharCompare function(index: sort "AAAB" before "AAAC"):

   ```
    function CharCompare(a, b, index) {
     if (index == a.length || index == b.length)
         return 0;
     //toUpperCase: isn't case sensitive
     var aChar = alphabets.indexOf(a.toUpperCase().charAt(index));
     var bChar = alphabets.indexOf(b.toUpperCase().charAt(index));
     if (aChar != bChar)
         return aChar - bChar
     else
         return CharCompare(a,b,index+1)
    }
   ```
5. Call OrderFunc for sorting the testArray(the result will be : A1,B2,C3,Č4,Ć5,D6).

[Test Online](https://jsbin.com/rinofociyo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Good Luck

Comment: @TheChetan. this is a custom order function and you can manage all the alphabets that you are going to sort. for example, Russian alphabet has 33 chars, Persian has 32 chars and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Use The Intl.Collator like you will get perfect sorting result

```
function letterSort(lang, letters) {
  letters.sort(new Intl.Collator(lang).compare);
  return letters;
}

console.log(letterSort('gu', ['છ','ક','ખ']));
// expected output: Array ["a", "ä", "z"]

console.log(letterSort('sv', ['a','z','ä']));
// expected output: Array ["a", "z", "ä"]
```

More detail you can check here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator