# comparing 2 strings alphabetically for sorting purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare 2 strings alphabetically for sorting purposes. For example I want to have a boolean check like `if('aaaa' < 'ab')`. I tried it, but it's not giving me correct results, so I guess that's not the right syntax. How do I do this in jquery or Javascript?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery?

Comment: That's how you do it. What result do you expect? The expression `'aaaa' < 'ab'` returns `true`. <! -- false edit to remove vote -->

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Lets look at some test cases - try running the following expressions in your JS console:

```
"a" < "b"

"aa" < "ab"

"aaa" < "aab"
```

All return true.

JavaScript compares strings character by character and "a" comes before "b" in the alphabet - hence less than.

In your case it works like so -

> 1 . "**a**​aaa" < "​**a**​b"

compares the first two "a" characters - all equal, lets move to the next character.

> 2 .  "a​**a**​​aa" < "a​**b**​​"

compares the second characters "a" against "b" - whoop! "a" comes before "b". Returns true.

Comment: for discussion about special characters such as Č,č,Š,š,Ž,ž, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909126/javascript-sort-with-unicode

Comment: Impressive that this is built-in natively!

Comment: Something to keep in mind would be capitals. `"a" < "b" === true` `"a" < "B"  === false`.

Comment: Yes, it sorts asciibetically

Comment: @chrisjshields - oh wow - I've never heard that word before... I like it!

Answer (score 229):

You do say that the comparison is for sorting purposes. Then I suggest [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead:

```
"a".localeCompare("b");
```

It returns `-1` since `"a" < "b"`, `1` or `0` otherwise, like you need for [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Keep in mind that sorting is locale dependent. E.g. in German, `ä` is a variant of `a`, so `"ä".localeCompare("b", "de-DE")` returns `-1`. In Swedish, `ä` is one of the last letters in the alphabet, so `"ä".localeCompare("b", "sv-SE")` returns `1`.

Without the second parameter to `localeCompare`, the browser's locale is used. Which in my experience is never what I want, because then it'll sort differently than the server, which has a fixed locale for all users.

Also, if what you are sorting contains numbers, you may want:

```
"a5b".localeCompare("a21b", undefined, { numeric: true })
```

This returns -1, recognizing that 5 as a number is less than 21. Without `{ numeric: true }` it returns 1, since "2" sorts before "5". In many real-world applications, users expect "a5b" to come before "a21b".

Comment: +1 also worth mentioning that this is fine for cases too (`"aa".localeCompare("ab")` == "aa".localeCompare("Ab") for any locale I can think of) and works even in old versions of IE. Should be the accepted answer!

Comment: +1 for Peter; This is more compatible with how Javascript array sorting works anyway so it's more useful, and I think it's more of what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I suppose, this should be the right answer. The only way to make alphabetical (**not Unicode**) strings comparation.

Comment: This seemed to really do the trick, even for alphanumeric values. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Just remember that string comparison like "x" > "X" is case-sensitive

```
"aa" < "ab" //true
"aa" < "Ab" //false
```

You can use `.toLowerCase()` to compare without case sensitivity.

Answer (score 11):

Let's say we have an array of objects such as:

```
{ name: String }
```

then we can sort our array as follows:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name === b.name) return 0;
  return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Note: Be careful with uppercase letters. You may need to cast your string to lowercase depending on the purpose.

Comment: The function used for sorting is supposed to return 0 if they are equal.  This function only returns -1 or 1.

Comment: @Steve - well, *pragmatically* speaking, this is ok as nothing will change for the user. That said, I agree - this is not a spec-compliant comparator which leads to unnecessary swaps of equal strings. Won't be noticeable on small (or unique enough) arrays, but can slow things down on large collections with mostly identical elements.

Comment: A good point here is that a direct comparison returns a boolean, which is not enough to operate an array sorting and will actually lead to incorrect results. For sorting, one has to return 0, 1 or -1.

Answer (score 8):

`"a".localeCompare("b")` should actually return `-1` since `a` sorts before `b`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp

Comment: If you meant this as a comment to my answer, you're right. My answer used to incorrectly show the result as 1, so I corrected that.