# Regex for determining if Alphanumeric code is in range

Tags: javascript, regex, icd

I'm working on an ICD10 diagnosis code application. I need to determine if one ICD10 code falls in a certain range. For example:

**Code:** 4A1H7EZ

**Range:** 4A1H7CZ - 4A1H7HZ

This should return '**True**'.

I've tried converting the alpha characters to numbers (a=0, b=1 etc) but the resulting number conflicts with other ranges/codes.

Regex isn't my strong point, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The code/range above is just an example of the format

Comment: Regex is not good at ranges. Could you use a "range" (alphabetically between ...)?

Comment: @Kieran: but Tushar's expression is a regex and it works correctly on your example. If it nevertheless is not what you are looking for, you should adjust your question.

Comment: @Jongware: It does work on the _example_. The ranges change though as well as the codes. I need a dynamic solution

Comment: @Kieran: therefore you need to provide more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use regex?
As seen here in [comparing 2 strings alphabetically for sorting purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198257/comparing-2-strings-alphabetically-for-sorting-purposes)
javascript auto compares strings.

So `"4A1H7EZ" > "4A1H7CZ" && "4A1H7EZ" < "4A1H7HZ"` will return `true`

Comment: Interesting but only works if the last digits are always letters. In my case, the last 2 digits could be alphanumeric. Example: _4A0J72Z_

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you - `"4A0J723" > "4A0J722"` yields `true`. However I did not mention that letters are "larger" than numbers so `"4A0J72Z" > "4A0J729"` will also yield `true` and also there is a difference between cased letters

Comment: Sorry, been busy. This actually seems to work quite well on all the tests I've performed so far

Comment: Yes, good solution, but you might get caught out by `X` which is a padding character, not a diagnostic indicator (except when it is the initial character). There are sometimes decimal places used, which you'd have to remove before comparison. Finally, you can hit very subtle encoding issues on different platforms, e.g. once I found spaces were ignored in string comparison on some platforms, but not others. You might want to make sure that the ICD codes are ASCII. My R package `icd9` (`icd10` branch on github) https://github.com/jackwasey/icd9/tree/icd10 has lots of regexes for ICD-10 codes.

Answer (score 1):

David has the right answer for doing this in Javascript.

However, an "ICD10 diagnosis code application" probably *should* be using a database; and given that, you should really solve this with SQL, in which case it would be trivial.

A query like this would return any range that matched a given code:

```
select * from ranges where diag_code between range_start and range_end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop and compare each index one by one. With somethings like that:

```
for entry, index in code:
  if entry.isNumeric:
      if range[index] < entry and rang2[index] > entry:
         return false

  else
      if compareAlpha(range[index], entry) > 1 and compareAlpha(range2[index], entry ) < 0:
         return false
return true
```

(not tested)