# React Material UI Table Name Sorting seems little bit off

Tags: reactjs, sorting, material-ui

Quick question about sorting the table. Anyone can explain why it's not sorting ASC or DESC example taken straight from Material UI Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/13r5l3qyz3,

Results:

```
Gargantua
Koala Den
aorro
```

or

```
aorro
Koala Den
Gargantua
```

Thanks

Comment: ASC and DESC work for me

Comment: Shouldn't 'k' come after 'g'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior comes from the way the sort is implemented in this example. Here's the sort function (line 215 in the CodeSandbox you linked to):

```
const data =
  order === "desc"
    ? this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy] ? -1 : 1))
    : this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (a[orderBy] < b[orderBy] ? -1 : 1));
```

Assuming that you're ordering by `name` and `order === "desc"`, that'll basically boil down to:

```
const data = this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (b.name < a.name ? -1 : 1));
```

So, the final order will be a result of comparisons that look like this:

```
"Koala Den" < "aorro"
"Gargantua" < "Koala Den"
```

But, JavaScript string comparison [can have surprising results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198257/comparing-2-strings-alphabetically-for-sorting-purposes). Specifically, since the `K` in `"Koala Den"` is uppercase and the `a` in `"aorro"` is lowercase, this will be the result:

```
"Koala Den" < "aorro" // true
"Gargantua" < "Koala Den" // true
```

So, the sort is working as expected given the sorting method used. It's just not a case-insensitive string sort like you might expect.

You can check this by making `"aorro"` start with an uppercase `A`. Then the sort will have the expected results.

To fix this problem, the sort function would probably have to be re-implemented to work with all of the types that could be present in each column.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the data to lower/upper case while comparing helps solve the problem. This also works for strings starting with numbers.
(i.e. for an array like ['Aeon', '3F Works', 'mBand', 'MAQ']
Here is the sample code:

```
  const data =
      order === "desc"
        ? this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (b[orderBy].toLowerCase() < a[orderBy].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1))
        : this.state.data.sort((a, b) => (a[orderBy].toLowerCase() < b[orderBy].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1));
```