# How to sort an array of object based on number and string (Arabic names)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Here is my snippet which has names in Arabic (i.e I want to show some data for Saudi Arabia)

I have tried local `compare()`  method but doesn't work

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": "4231a075-ac9d-4c58-b6c2-2d4cf73d72e1",
    "name": "النَّشاطُ الثّالِثُ - وَرْشَةُ الْكِتابَةِ 2",
    "author": "na",
    "countryCode": "SA",
    "createdAt": "2019-10-06T07:30:16.770Z",
    "pageId": "188"
  },
  {
    "id": "fde7d816-4eb8-4c82-a875-23hsd",
    "name": "النَّشاطُ الثّاني - وَرْشَةُ الْكِتابَةِ 1",
    "author": "na",
    "countryCode": "SA",
    "createdAt": "2019-10-06T07:30:16.770Z",
    "pageId": "188"
  }
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.pageId - b.pageId || a.name.localeCompare(b.name, ["ar"]);
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The names in your example start with `1` and `2` – where do you see much to compare _after_ that? `1 < 2` is pretty independent from any locale.

Comment: Try putting  b in place of 1,  and a in place of 2, and it sorts properly.

Comment: @ChrisMedina Medina
 this I will get from some API, I cant re-order it, i should sort in my front end app (react js)

Comment: @CBore 
some times I won't get the numbers in name field simply I will get the some Arabic name

Comment: @Ramusesan have you tried to sort the array with Intl.Collator ?

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909126/javascript-sort-with-unicode

Comment: @pbachman  Yes I tried but no changes .

Comment: can somebody help me on this with working example with arbic

Comment: @CBroe can please elaborate your answer

Comment: It is always a problem when combining numbers with Arabic text; the number does not get placed properly into the string. I suffer from this in excel too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the numbers you entered with the Arabic text are not proper Arabic encoded. Now seems all fine and sorts properly.

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": "4231a075-ac9d-4c58-b6c2-2d4cf73d72e1",
    "name": "2 النَّشاطُ الثّالِثُ - وَرْشَةُ الْكِتابَةِ",
    "author": "na",
    "countryCode": "SA",
    "createdAt": "2019-10-06T07:30:16.770Z",
    "pageId": "188"
  },
  {
    "id": "fde7d816-4eb8-4c82-a875-23hsd",
    "name": "1 النَّشاطُ الثّاني - وَرْشَةُ الْكِتابَةِ",
    "author": "na",
    "countryCode": "SA",
    "createdAt": "2019-10-06T07:30:16.770Z",
    "pageId": "188"
  }
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.pageId - b.pageId || a.name.localeCompare(b.name, ["ar"]);
});
console.log(arr)
```