# JavaScript: Sort mixed array of ASCII string and non-ASCII strings

Tags: javascript

For example I have an array

```
let fruits = ["apple", "яблоко", "grape"]
```

When I do

```
let result = fruits.sort()
```

Result will be

```
["apple", "grape", "яблоко"]
```

But I want unicode items to be at the start of result array.

Comment: `sort` accepts a callback with that you can define how the sorting should happen. If you are not able to get it work with you custom callback, then show that callback and explain what incorrect result you get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618442/2569323

Comment: They're all unicode strings.

Comment: Do you want to have all strings that start with a non ASCII character at the beginning of the array? So also strings starting with `è`, `à`, `à`, `ä`, ... ?

Comment: @melpomene you can change the question title if you think this is incorrect wording.

Comment: It's incorrect thinking. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @melpomene  CertainPerformance gives the correct answer. Sorry if I could not provide right wording for my question.

Comment: It's still not about the wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if the string starts with a word character in the sort function:

```js
const fruits = ["apple", "яблоко", "grape"];
const isAlphabetical = str => /^\w/.test(str);
fruits.sort((a, b) => (
  isAlphabetical(a) - isAlphabetical(b)
    || a.localeCompare(b)
))
console.log(fruits);
```

A more robust sorting function would check each character against each other character:

```js
const fruits = ["apple", "яблоко", "grape", 'dog', 'foo', 'bar', 'локоfoo', 'fooлоко', 'foobar'];
const isAlphabetical = str => /^\w/.test(str);
const codePointValue = char => {
  const codePoint = char.codePointAt(0);
  return codePoint < 128 ? codePoint + 100000 : codePoint;
};
fruits.sort((a, b) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i >= b.length) return false;
    const compare = codePointValue(a[i]) - codePointValue(b[i]);
    if (compare !== 0) return compare;
  }
  return true;
})
console.log(fruits);
```