# Change special letter to normal

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

HI,

I want to change letter selected letters: "Ą" to "A", "ć" to C etc... in jQuery

currently my code changes letter to *

how to modify it to change given letters?

```
var finishedslug = slugcontent_hyphens.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'*');
```

Comment: You should also tag this JavaScript, I don't see any jQuery in your above code snippet or the necessary need for jQuery.

Comment: @omnosis those are HTML entities, not accented characters.

Comment: not really matters. change characters or html entites, no difference. btw the second link is absolute better.

Comment: ok I've found the answer there