# Sorting Accented Characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort a list of strings with accented characters e.g.`["Zebra", "Apple", "Ähhhh"]` and I want it to look like `["Apple", "Ähhhh", "Zebra"]`

Just running `list.sort()` gives me `["Apple","Zebra","Ähhhh"]`

Is there another built in function (like `localeCompare`) that will let me sort this in the way I want it to be?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want `Ä`s to come after `A`s, is that the logic you're looking for?

Comment: What locale do you want to use, so that `Ä` comes after `A`?

Comment: By the way, you're question may already have an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624532/locale-based-sort-in-javascript-sort-accented-letters-and-other-variants-in-a-p, though your's is much more succinctly worded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, yes, you can sort by different locale.

```
let ar = ["Apple","Zebra","Ähhhh"];

ar.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en'))
```

However, as to the exact sorting you're looking for, you'll have to replace 'en' with the appropriate locale, if there is one.

Comment: This results in `"Ähhhh",
  "Apple",
  "Zebra"`, which isn't what OP is looking for

Comment: @CertainPerformance, hence my last sentence.  I still put it as an answer because I suspect that he's really looking for accented a's and non-accented a's to be together, and would respect the locale if it it does it differently than what he asked for.