# Apache spark text similarity

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying the below example in java

[Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark)

This is my code

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\del");

        List<MyRecord> firstRow = new ArrayList<MyRecord>();
        firstRow.add(new App().new MyRecord("1", "Love is blind"));

        List<MyRecord> secondRow = new ArrayList<MyRecord>();
        secondRow.add(new App().new MyRecord("1", "Luv is blind"));

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("LSHExample").config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset firstDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(firstRow, MyRecord.class);
        Dataset secondDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(secondRow, MyRecord.class);

        firstDataFrame.show(20, false);
        secondDataFrame.show(20, false);

        RegexTokenizer regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
                .setPattern("\\W");
        NGram ngramTransformer = new NGram().setN(3).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("ngrams");
        HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("ngrams").setOutputCol("vectors");
        MinHashLSH minHashLSH = new MinHashLSH().setInputCol("vectors").setOutputCol("lsh");

        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
        .setStages(new PipelineStage[] { regexTokenizer, ngramTransformer, hashingTF, minHashLSH });

        PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(firstDataFrame);

        Dataset dataset1 = model.transform(firstDataFrame);
        dataset1.show(20,false);

        Dataset dataset2 = model.transform(secondDataFrame);
        dataset2 .show(20,false);

        Transformer[] transformers = model.stages();
        MinHashLSHModel temp = (MinHashLSHModel) transformers[transformers.length - 1];
        temp.approxSimilarityJoin(dataset1, dataset2, 0.01).show(20,false);

    }

    protected class MyRecord {
        private String id;
        private String text;

        private MyRecord(String id, String text) {
            this.id = id;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

    }

}
```

Before invoking the *approxSimilarityJoin* the two datasets look like below.

**Transformed Dataset A**

```
+---+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------------+
|id |text         |words            |ngrams         |vectors                |lsh             |
+---+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------------+
|1  |Love is blind|[love, is, blind]|[love is blind]|(262144,[243005],[1.0])|[[2.02034596E9]]|
+---+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------------+
```

**Transformed Dataset B**

```
+---+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------------+----------------+
|id |text        |words           |ngrams        |vectors               |lsh             |
+---+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------------+----------------+
|2  |Luv is blind|[luv, is, blind]|[luv is blind]|(262144,[57733],[1.0])|[[7.79808048E8]]|
+---+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

Though the two texts "Love is blind" and "Luv is blind"  are almost similar , I get the below blank output.

```
+--------+--------+-------+
|datasetA|datasetB|distCol|
+--------+--------+-------+
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Kindly revert If there is any mistake in the above code .

I tested by giving the same input for both data sets and below is the output. The distCol is zero when both the datasets have same text.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|datasetA                                                                                                                        |datasetB                                                                                                                        |distCol|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),WrappedArray(love is blind),(262144,[243005],[1.0]),WrappedArray([2.02034596E9])]|[2,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),WrappedArray(love is blind),(262144,[243005],[1.0]),WrappedArray([2.02034596E9])]|0.0    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

The below example also uses the same concept.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/09/detecting-abuse-scale-locality-sensitive-hashing-uber-engineering.html

I think I am missing some fundamental aspect in this program. Kindly revert.

---

It worked based upon the suggestions given by user8371915 .

I removed the ngram and increased the numHashTables

```
MinHashLSH minHashLSH = new MinHashLSH().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("hashValues").setNumHashTables(20);
```

Now I am able to relate how this matching works

Below are my two dataset

**Dataset A**

```
+---+-------------+
|id |text         |
+---+-------------+
|1  |Love is blind|
+---+-------------+
```

**Dataset B**

```
+---+-------------------------+
|id |text                     |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |Love is blind            |
|2  |Luv is blind             |
|3  |Lov is blind             |
|4  |This is totally different|
|5  |God is love              |
|6  |blind love is divine     |
+---+-------------------------+
```

and the final output is below

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|datasetA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |datasetB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |distCol|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]                            |0.0    |
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|[2,Luv is blind,WrappedArray(luv, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,84987],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-2.021501434E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-6.70773282E8], [-6.93210471E8], [-1.205754635E9], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [4.46435174E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.036250081E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]                              |0.5    |
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|[5,God is love,WrappedArray(god, is, love),(262144,[15889,57304,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-7.6253133E7], [-2.6669178E7], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.060055906E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-9.83191394E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.04032919E9], [-1.373403353E9], [-5.63413619E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.7390215E9], [-1.745820849E9], [8.1559665E7], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.635066748E9], [6.38995945E8], [-1.59718287E9])]                                        |0.5    |
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|[6,blind love is divine,WrappedArray(blind, love, is, divine),(262144,[15889,25596,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-1.627956291E9], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.93451596E9], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [-1.152091375E9], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-8.50494401E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|0.25   |
|[1,Love is blind,WrappedArray(love, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,186480],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.815588486E9], [-1.411500923E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-8.0411681E7], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-9.33829921E8], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.48476096E8], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.997519365E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-5.92484283E8], [-1.869738298E9])]|[3,Lov is blind,WrappedArray(lov, is, blind),(262144,[15889,48831,81946],[1.0,1.0,1.0]),WrappedArray([-1.06555007E9], [-1.557513224E9], [-1.590526534E9], [-2.83593282E8], [-1.88316392E9], [-1.776275893E9], [-6.93210471E8], [-1.39927757E8], [-1.713286948E9], [-1.698342316E9], [-1.164990332E9], [-1.240833109E9], [-1.519529732E9], [-1.882820721E9], [-7.50906814E8], [1.99715481E8], [-1.036250081E9], [-1.380314819E9], [-1.808919173E9], [-1.869738298E9])]                            |0.5    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

- If you use `NGrams` consider more granular tokenizer. The goal here is to correct for misspellings:

  ```
  RegexTokenizer regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
     .setInputCol("text")
     .setOutputCol("words")
     .setPattern("");

  NGram ngramTransformer = new NGram()
    .setN(3)
    .setInputCol("words")
    .setOutputCol("ngrams");
  ```

  With your current code (`NGram(3)` and sentence three words split by `\W`) three you'll get only one token and no similarity.
- Increase number of hash tables (`setNumHashTables`) for LSH. Default value (1) is to small for anything but simple examples.
- Normalize Unicode strings. There is a Scala `Transformer` in [What is the best way to remove accents with apache spark dataframes in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38359534/8371915)
- Remove capitalization. You can use [`SQLTransformer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#sqltransformer):

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer

  val sqlTrans = new SQLTransformer().setStatement(
     "SELECT *, lower(normalized_text) FROM __THIS__")
  ```