# Equivalent method for replacing the latin accents to English Letters using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, foundry-code-repositories

I am trying to replace the latin/other non-english characters into english letters for large number of records; something as below using Pyspark;

```
'ä':'a',
'ö':'o',
'ü':'u',
'ẞ':'s',
'á':'a',
 and more
```

In Python; i could find the built in functions in python from unicodedata library [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) for a string;

`s1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'string').encode('ASCII', 'ignore')`

and for Pandas dataframe using [pyspark.pandas.Series.str.normalize](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.Series.str.normalize.html)

In case of above; it requires conversion of the Pyspark DataFrame to Pandas -> performing the normalization of strings -> and Converstion back into PySpark dataframe; all of these steps which consume memory and time.

I am willing to know if there exists a way to perform these replacements of the latin/other characters in Pyspark.

The following are something i have tried;

a. Manually mapping all the characters to english letters using [.replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html)

`pySpark_df = pySpark_df .replace(to_replace=normalize_mapping, subset=['col_name'])`

However the mapping is incomplete as the total such mappings/variations outweighs than what i could manually collect.

b. Use of Regular expressions and replacement using regex_replace [regex_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace)

Using Regex, i could not find any patterns for me to make these replacements with english letter. I can see this this thread being helpful [What is the best way to remove accents with Apache Spark dataframes in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359534/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-with-apache-spark-dataframes-in-pyspark)

However the mentioned dependencies are not supported in the platform i work on (Foundry by Palantir). `i.e bin/pyspark --jars path-to/target/scala-2.11/unicode-normalization_2.11-1.0.jar \ --driver-class-path path-to/target/scala-2.11/unicode-normalization_2.11-1.0.jar`

Will appreciate any insights especially if these replacements can be achieved via regex in PySpark.

Edit:
Currently we have UDF which does the above task. However having this task performed by Pyspark in a distributed way is something we would like to check for.

Comment: have you tried a simple UDF?

Comment: We have already UDF implemented. However , we wish to get rid of it given the volume of the records we deal with and see if pyspark version helps us scale better.

Answer (score 2):

Using an [F.pandas_udf()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) will provide much better performance than a regular `F.udf()` since it uses apache Arrow to send data into the python process in batches, and operates on it in a vectorized manner using pandas.

Something along the lines of:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf(T.StringType())
def remove_accents(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    # I'm not a pandas expert, maybe there's a better native way to do the encode step than with a lambda like this.
    return s.str.normalize("NFKD").map(lambda s: s.encode("ASCII", "ignore")) 

df = df.withColumn("cleaned_column", remove_accents("some_column"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use an UDF but it does not work for every char (ẞ for example):

```py
import unicodedata

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a = [
    ("ä", "a"),
    ("ö", "o"),
    ("ü", "u"),
    ("ẞ", "s"),
    ("á", "a"),
]

b = ["to_change", "ref"]


df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)


normalize_udf = F.udf(
    lambda x: unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", x).encode("ASCII", "ignore").decode("ASCII")
)


df.withColumn("new", normalize_udf(F.col("to_change"))).show()
```

```
+---------+---+---+                                                             
|to_change|ref|new|
+---------+---+---+
|        ä|  a|  a|
|        ö|  o|  o|
|        ü|  u|  u|
|        ẞ|  s|   |
|        á|  a|  a|
+---------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the version we have at the moment. However i am looking at the possibility to have it helped by PySpark efficiency to see if i can improve the runtime.