# The preg_replace should not cut out words

Tags: php, preg-replace

My code:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["title"])));
```

Example, when i write: `Úm Titulo`, I get: `-m-titulo`. As you can see, i missed the `Ú`. When i write: `Úm Titulo`. I should get `um-titulo`. How to fix it? The `preg_replace` should not cut out words with accentuation.

Answer (score 0):

The `/[^a-z0-9]+/i` pattern matches 1+ chars that are not ASCII letters and digits. It matches `Я`, `ё`, `ł`, `ę` and many more letters.

You may use

```
preg_replace('~[\W_]+~u', '-', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5jppdc/4).

Here, `[\W_]` matches any char that is not a Unicode letter or digit (`\W` does not match `_`, thus, `_` is added to the character class).

The [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) makes `\W` Unicode-aware.

To also change all Unicode letters to their base forms, normalize the string:

```
$result = strtolower( preg_replace('~[\W_]+~u', '-', normalizer_normalize($text, Normalizer::NFKC)) );
```

**NOTE**: Make sure *`php_intl.dll`* extension is enabled.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5jppdc/3 as you can see, the preg_repace only put "-" on the first word, and it don't replace the `Úm` with `um`.

Comment: @Sabrina If you want to also deaccent the string, you need to use the corresponding function. You won't be able to achieve that with regex only.

Comment: That's all i need to do? Another thing, how do i replace my code, with yours? Mine is: `$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["title"])));`

Comment: @Sabrina `$slug = preg_replace('/[\W_]+/u', '-', trim(strtolower(normalizer_normalize($_POST["title"], Normalizer::NFKC))));`. Also, [here are hints on enabling the normalization support](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

Comment: I put `Úm Titulo Muito` and it outputs `Úm-titulo-muito`, it should outputs `um-titulo-muito`... Did you forgot something?

Comment: @Sabrina I can't repro, the `normalizer_normalize($text, Normalizer::NFKC)` part removes accents, `preg_replace('~[\W_]+~u', '-', $res)` replaces all non-alnum char chunks with `-`, and `strtolower` should make it lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your regex, as it does not account for letters with accent marks?
Refer to the following:

[Replacing Accented Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones)