# custom javascript regex like wordpress page tile

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I'm on react and i'm working on a input that display Url path like wordpress page title, you put a title in the input and it display the path of the page onBlur...

I managed to do the whole thing but i still need a custom regex to display the Url for the value of the input:

using (.replace())

- I need to trim the white space at the end and at the beginning
- replace all the white space by ('-') but prevent from having 2 in a row
- replace the specials characters by ('-')
- replace letters like ç ñ ö é ì .etc by c n o e i

is there someone who can help me with that?

Comment: what do you want to happen when there are multiple dashes in a row? condense to a single?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you are trying to do, or what you have tried yourself so people providing answers can avoid suggesting what you've already done?

Comment: Better add some input and output examples

Comment: Sorry guys I spend 18 hours working on websites and when i'm reading this i can see how confusing it is now.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I didn't try anything i'm not good with regex myself. I googled this but didn't fin anything that suited my needs

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces yes this would be the best thing to do

Comment: @user3359675 ok, give my submitted answer a try, adding replacements for the diacritic characters you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take. You'll need to add some lines for additional diacritic characters (accented characters) that you want to replace. Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones) for someone else who did it.

**Update**: using `.normalize` instead of specifying each diacritic replacement

```js
function clearResult(){
  document.getElementById('result').value = "";
}

function stripUrl(){

  var text = document.getElementById('input').value;

  var newText = text.trim()
    .normalize('NFKD')
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .replace(/[^\w/:.]/gi, '-') //clean up special characters
    .replace(/-{2,}/gi,'-'); //handle multiple dashes

  document.getElementById('result').value = newText;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="https://google.com/)!(#$!*$ assfsd/       /mañana/aaa" style="width:500px;" onchange="clearResult()"/>
<button onclick="stripUrl()">StripUrl</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="result" style="width:500px;"/>
```

Comment: I use this replacing all the .replace(...) by .normalize('NFKD') for the diacritics but i noticed that when i type ça va? it displays c-a-va while i need it to be ca-va same thing for mañana which displays man-ana how can i fix that?

Comment: I added in the replacement for ñ above as an additional example. It returns "manana". If you add the same replace for your "c" diacritics, it will work as intended

Comment: doesn't work for me cause i edited the code like this https://codepen.io/Aastone/pen/gQJRWV

Comment: @user3359675 ah, missed that you're using `.normalize`. This method ensures that the diacritics are unicode, then we can replace the unicode characters with their ascii counterparts (better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/4705727)). Otherwise, answer has been updated

Comment: Thanks working good, if someone else is finding this and want to use it and using french language add this .replace(/[œ]/g,"oe") so you can get for example the word coeur when you writing cœur instead of c-ur

Comment: @user3359675 glad to help. please mark this as the answer when you get the chance