# Case and diacritic insensitive autocomplete with comboBox (ActiveX) in Visual basic (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, case-insensitive

I am using Visual Basic to build a macro in Excel. I have a `comboBox` (ActiveX) linked to a range of cells to allow for autocomplete.

I would like the input text to be **case and diacritic insensitive**.

For example, let's say I am looking for the word `"alàlà"`. I would like this suggestion to come up even if for example the input text is `"Alala"`.

Would anyone have an idea?

Comment: Split the string into a character array, then loop through it and apply a lookup table to or regex to each character. Take the result of that and roll it up into a custom equity check.

Comment: Thx. I see what you mean, so I guess there is no easier way to deal with it, like a kind of object property to change?

Comment: This might help create your mapping table.https://stackoverflow.com/a/18123985/4839827