# Matching a string containing special characters against a string without special characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, diacritics, google-query-language

I'm trying to match strings using a Google Sheets query where both strings are uncertain if they contain special characters. I'll try to explain as best as I can:

I have a table of data

```
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  A  |   B  |  C  |  D  |
|x    | y    |ø    |z    |
|xx   | yy   |á    |zz   |
|xxx  | yyy  |e    |zzz  |
+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

My query function would look something like this:

```
=QUERY(A1:D3, "SELECT * WHERE (C = 'ø') OR (C = 'è') OR (C = 'a')")
```

> Currently, using this query will only return 1 row because, `(C = 'ø')` is an exact match with 'ø', however none of the others have a match.

> For `(C = 'è')`, we can just replace all of the accented characters in the string with their un-accented equivalent.
> In this case 'è' becomes 'e' and has a match - now the query will return a second row.
>
> (I found a nice way to replace all accented characters in a string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones).)

> Finally, here is where my main problem sits: `(C = 'a')`. I can't figure out a way to make it match 'á', unless I check every accented variant of 'a', but that just seems silly.
> It's not possible to do something like `"... WHERE (CUSTOM_FUNCTION(C) = 'a')"` either, sadly.

As I previously mentioned, either side of the match may or may not contain accented/special characters.
I should also mention that it wont be just a single character, it will be a whole string.

If anyone has any possible solutions to this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `QUERY` formula, you could use a `FILTER` formula.

```
=FILTER(A2:D22,REGEXMATCH(C2:C22,"ø|è|á")=TRUE)
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs. You can also add/remove more special characters.)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)