# Query with latin characters

Tags: breeze

I'm building a search field. When users type "a", server will return results with contain "a", latin chacracters will be accepted too.

Example:
User: type "a".
Server return: á, à, ă, A, Á,...

I have read this link: [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

but I don't know how to use with query string.

Comment: Are you saying that the server will match "a" with á, à, ă, A, Á,...?  Are you asking how to compose a query that turns the user's "á, à, ă, A, Á,..." into "a" *before* composing the query?

Comment: Assume Server has 4 record (string): Lá, Là, LA, B. When User type "A", Server will return: Lá, Là, LA. I dont know how to handle with these characters.