# Generate a friendly urls using UTF-8 encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url, generator, slug

I am trying to make friendly url from title.
I find out many solutions but it has still problem with unicode character. 
eg: 'xin chào' in vietnamese

I saw https://sluggenerator.com/ was OK. Could anyone helps me to do like this by javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider making the title of this question more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the answers of this question:

[Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

The examples in the above page are for other languages than vietnamese, with much less types of accented characters, so I would advise you to write some special letter-substitution code suited for your language, which is not hard, given you have a starting point as the ones in the answers for the question above.