# Do space characters in script/html tags stop XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

Did not see this technique here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

and am hoping to better understand why.

---

I have the following function (courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/a/287173/2144912):

```
comment = comment.replace(/&(amp|quot|#x27|gt|lt);/g, function (c) {
    return {
        '&amp;': '&',
        '&quot;': '"',
        '&#x27;': "'",
        '&gt;': '> ',
        '&lt;': '< ',
    }[c]
})
```

which is used to display user-inputed comments **that have already been HTML-escaped** using Underscore's `_.escape()` function, and that:

1. Allow for the use of special characters that are normally escaped (&, <, >, ', ")
2. While (hopefully) preventing XSS

Please note the how `&gt;` and `&lt;` are returning values with an extra space: `'< '` and `'> '`.

In testing, if the user were to input:

```
<h1>here is some html</h1>
```

The output would is a string (not HTML):

```
< h1> test< /h1>
```

Is this a valid XSS prevention technique?

Comment: it might work, but why undo the escaping in the first place?

Comment: depends on the rendering engine and how dumb/smart it is `<foo` is a valid start-of-tag, `< foo` is not, but that doesn't mean some engine out there will pretend like it knows better and treat it as the spaceless-proper version isntead.

Comment: @dandavis - to allow users to use special characters. Example: 'west coast > east coast'.

Comment: _“Is this a valid XSS prevention technique?”_ – it looks like a great way of generating invalid, faulty HTML. If that’s not what you are looking for – then it’s just utter nonsense.

Comment: _“to allow users to use special characters. Example: 'west coast > east coast'”_ – notice how you can post that here in comments without any problems? Even stuff like <script>alert("foo")</script> …? Go look at the source code of this site to find out how SO outputs it …

Comment: you display `west coast > east coast` using the input you had: `west coast &gt; east coast` if you undo it the escaping, you open yourself up to lord-only-knows what quirks, especially in pre-HTML5 browsers, and to `onmouseover`-style XSS

Comment: "If that’s not what you are looking for – then it’s just utter nonsense" @CBroe, good point.