# String.replace for multiple unique characters and replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

After reading MDN documentation, as well as W3schools, I'm still unsure of how to use .replace to replace multiple special characters all with their own unique replacement.

So if I write a function that takes a string as an argument, that string may be different each time, with special characters in each string. I want to be able to write a single replace statement that will check for those special characters and then depending up which special character is found, replace that character with a corresponding unique replacement.

An example, if I pass a string like `dave & dave` I may want to replace the & symbol with the characters "and" instead, which is simple enough, but what if the next string that is passed to the function has a $ that I want to replace with "dollar".

I can create such a function for a single unique character with replacement like:

```
string.replace(/&/g, "and");
```

But I'm not sure how to have multiple characters checked and then replaced with particular unique replacements.

Comment: you could stack the `replace` like `string.replace(/&/g,'and').replace(/$/g,'dollar');`

Comment: @depperm: It is called *chaining*.

Comment: @Chirpizard: See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8nzphj03/).

Comment: @stribizhev Nice solution, similar to the solution posted below. I think this one is actually easier to follow. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Ok, I would close your question as a dupe of [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string), but ... no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a replacement function, something like:

```js
var st = "& $ % !";

var replaced = st.replace(/[&$%!]/g, 
  function(piece) {
    var replacements = {
      "&": "and",
      "$": "dollar",
      "%": "pct",
      "!": "bang"
    };
  
    return replacements[piece] || piece;
  });

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: This does work! The only thing I don't understand is the `piece` argument passed into the function. How is the `piece`/symbol to be replaced get passed as the argument? Thanks for this solution, also!

Comment: That's what `replace` *does* when you pass a function as the second argument. It passes each match to your function, and you return the replacement for that match.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation!