# How to compare two UTF-8 strings which contain diacritic characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an element like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shwbnefe/) but I have a problem to compare my strings when a string has a UTF-8 character because `"é" is > at all basics letters`.

```
<ol class="ingredientList">
    <li class="ingredient">Apples</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Carrots</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Clams</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Oysters</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Wheat</li>
</ol>
<ol class="ingredientList">
    <li class="ingredient">Barley</li>
    <li class="ingredient">éggs</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Millet</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Oranges</li>
    <li class="ingredient">Olives</li>
</ol>
```

```js
$(".ingredient").click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var added = false;
    var targetList = $(this).parent().siblings(".ingredientList")[0];
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(".ingredient", targetList).each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() > $(element).text()) {
                $(element).insertBefore($(this)).fadeIn("fast");
                added = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!added) $(element).appendTo($(targetList)).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Do you have any solutions to fix that ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `localeCompare()` method to sort text which contains diacritics. Try this:

```
$(".ingredient").click(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var $targetList = $element.closest('.ingredientList').siblings().first();

    $element.fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $element.appendTo($targetList);    
        $(".ingredient", $targetList).sort(function(a, b) {
            return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
        }).appendTo($targetList);
        $element.fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shwbnefe/2/)

Note that I amended your logic to make the selectors more efficient, and also to enable the sort algorithm.

[localeCompare MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: i liked `localeCompare()` method.

Comment: I can't use the sort method. This fiddle isn't the mirror of my code. I don't just have `<ul> <li></li> </ul> ...`. Here is my code. And the text value is so far in the DOM http://pastebin.com/pEsh8nAH

Comment: The structure there will still work with `sort()` you just need to sort the `div` elements instead of the `.ingredient`. If you can create a jsFiddle with your actual HTML structure I ca n show you how to do it.

Comment: I'm actually on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prbjz9d7/ but the animation doesn't work. Could you show me how to do this with the sort ?

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, you may want to replace the accentuated characters:
[Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-diacritics-in-strings)