# Filtering a list of strings based on user locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization

When working on a JavaScript project with AngularJS 1.6, I have a list of strings which I'd like to filter. For instance, assume my list contains *árbol*, *cigüeña*, *nido* and *tubo*.

When filtering strings in Spanish, if I filtered for "u", I'd expect both *cigüeña* and *tubo* to appear, which would be the most natural result for a Spaniard. However, this is not the case in German - u and ü are different letters and thus a German will not want to see *cigüeña* on the list. So I am looking for a way to make my list filtering aware of the user's locale.

I happen to have an object containing lots of diacritics, such that:

```
diacritics["á"] = "a";
diacritics["ü"] = "u";
// and so on...
```

This is what my filtering code looks like:

```
function matches(word, search) {
    var cleanWord = removeDiacritics(word.toLowerCase());
    var cleanSearch = removeDiacritics(search.toLowerCase());
    return cleanWord.indexOf(cleanSearch) > -1;
}

function removeDiacritics(word) {
    function match(a) {
        return diacritics[a] || a;
    }
    return text.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
}
```

The above code just removes all diacritics, so I thought to make it aware of the user's locale. Thus, I changed the match() function to this:

```
function match(a) {
    if (diacritics[a] && a.localeCompare(diacritics[a] === 0) {
        return diacritics[a];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The localeCompare function returns the same values when comparing "u" and "ü" with the German and Spanish locales, so that was not the answer here. I've gone over the [reference for the localeCompare method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and tried the usage and sensitivity options, but they don't seem to help much here.

How could I tweak my code for this to work? Is there any library which can handle this properly for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go about getting the user's locale directly from the browser via `navigator` ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator)), an object representing the user agent:

```
var language = navigator.language;
```

This will assign `language` the locale code of the user's browser, in my case `en-US`. I found [this site](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php) helpful for finding locale code's to test other regions of the world.

My `strFromLocale` function is comparable to your `removeDiacritics` function:

```
function strFromLocale(str) {
    function match(letter) {
        function letterMatch(letter, normalizedLetter) {
            var location = new Intl.Collator(language, {usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' }).compare(letter, normalizedLetter);
            return (location == 0)
        }
        normalizedLetter = letter.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/gi, "")
        if ( letterMatch(letter, normalizedLetter) ) {
            return normalizedLetter;
        } else {
            return letter;
        }
    }
    return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
}
```

Note the line with `Intl.Collator` ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator)). This line compares the diacritic with the normalized letter of the diacritic and checks the given language's alphabet for positional differences. Therefore:

```
/* English */
new Intl.Collator('en-US', {usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' }).compare('u', 'ü');
>>> 0

/* Swedish */
new Intl.Collator('sv', {usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' }).compare('u', 'ü');
>>> -1

/* German */
new Intl.Collator('de', {usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' }).compare('u', 'ü');
>>> -1
```

As you can see in the `letterMatch` function, it returns true if and only if the result of `Intl.Collator` is `0`, indicating that there are no positional differences of the letter within the alphabet of that language meaning it is safe to replace.

With that, here are some tests of the `strFromLocale` function:

```
var language = navigator.language; // en-US
strFromLocale("cigüeña");
>>> ciguena

var language = 'sv' // Swedish
strFromLocale("cigüeña");
>>> cigüena

var language = 'de' // German
strFromLocale("cigüeña");
>>> cigüena

var language = 'es-mx' // Spanish - Mexico
strFromLocale("cigüeña");
>>> cigueña
```

Comment: I think there's a small mistake in your last snippet. I think the "location" variable should be called "language". Other than that, it's perfect!

Comment: @unpollito oops, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the ECMA 6 [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#toc) library. This will allow you to adjust sort order based on locale e.g.:

```
// in German, ä sorts with a
console.log(new Intl.Collator('de').compare('ä', 'z'));
// → a negative value

// in Swedish, ä sorts after z
console.log(new Intl.Collator('sv').compare('ä', 'z'));
// → a positive value
```

The `sensitivity: 'base'` option will automatically sort with/without diacritics.

```
// in German, ä has a as the base letter
console.log(new Intl.Collator('de', { sensitivity: 'base' }).compare('ä', 'a'));
// → 0

// in Swedish, ä and a are separate base letters
console.log(new Intl.Collator('sv', { sensitivity: 'base' }).compare('ä', 'a'));
// → a positive value
```

You can then sort your list into the correct order prior to populating your UI Widget.

Comment: Sadly, that's not working. It's essentially the same I mentioned in the localeCompare() bit: when comparing "u" and "ü", the results are the same in Spanish and German. That happens both with the Collator and localeCompare(), which is unsurprising as they're part of the same API.

Comment: After reading Cole's answer, I realize that what was missing in both my approach and your solution was to use simultaneously usage="search" and sensitivity="base". Once we do that, the collator can realize the difference between "u" and "ü" for Spanish and German, which doesn't happen if we leave "usage" out.