# language specific chars base letter and sorting

Tags: javascript, localization, locale

I'm trying to print out a sorted list of items and print the first letter as a "group" headline for each item. The code is used on the client side. .
The sorting works just fine, the problem is when language specific chars is sorted in another locale. For example is `å` treated as `a`in en-GB and `ñ` as `n` in most locales.
Is there any generic way to figure out if a character "belongs" to a locale in js?

- `Å` has the base of `a` in `en-US` & `es-ES`, should not be printed
- `Å` should be printed in `sv-SE`
- `Ñ` has the base of `n` in `en-US` & `sv-SE`, should not be
  printed
- `Ñ` should be printed in `es-ES`

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bodasozito/edit?js,console)

Including the most simple example to display the problem:

```
console.clear();
var sortedItems;
var uniqueStartLetters;
var locales = ['en-US', 'es-ES', 'sv-SE'];
var items = ['am', 'ån', 'ao', 'na', 'ñb', 'nc' ];

sortAlphabetically = (array, locale) => {
    const sortFunc = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' });    
    return array.sort(sortFunc);
}

render = sortedItems => {
    const processedLetters = {};
    const res = sortedItems.map((item) => {
      const firstLetter = item[0].toUpperCase();

      if (!processedLetters[firstLetter]) {
        processedLetters[firstLetter] = true;
          console.log(firstLetter);
      }
      console.log(item);  
    });
}

locales.map(locale => {
    console.log('\n' + 'Using locale: ' + locale);
    sortedItems = sortAlphabetically(items, locale);
    render(sortedItems, uniqueStartLetters);
})
```

Comment: Is this for client-side or server-side usage?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It's for client side

Comment: Unicode CLDR data contains `exemplarCharacters` in its miscellaneous information. Here's the [misc file for Swedish](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-misc-modern/blob/master/main/sv/characters.json). Maybe that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with some tips from the following [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329596/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-user-locale/47368424#47368424)

```
console.clear();
var sortedItems;
var locales = ['en-US', 'es-ES', 'sv-SE', 'de-DE'];
var items = ['am', 'ån', 'ao', 'na', 'ñb', 'nc', 'ua', 'üb', 'uc', 'va' ];

strFromLocale = (str, locale) => {
    match = (letter) => {
        letterMatch = (letter, normalizedLetter) => {
            var location = new Intl.Collator(locale, { usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' }).compare(letter, normalizedLetter);
            return (location == 0)
        }
        normalizedLetter = letter.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/gi, "")
        if ( letterMatch(letter, normalizedLetter) ) {
            return normalizedLetter;
        } else {
            return letter;
        }
    }
    return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
}


sortAlphabetically = (array, locale) => {
    const sortFunc = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, locale, { usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'base' });    
    return array.sort(sortFunc);
}

render = (sortedItems, locale) => {
    const processedLetters = {};
    const res = sortedItems.map((item, index) => {      
      const firstLetter = strFromLocale(item[0].toUpperCase(), locale);  

      if (!processedLetters[firstLetter]) {
        processedLetters[firstLetter] = true;
          console.log(firstLetter);
      }
      console.log(item);  
    });
}

locales.map(locale => {
    console.log('\n' + 'Using locale: ' + locale);
    sortedItems = sortAlphabetically(items, locale);
    render(sortedItems, locale);    
})
```