# How to transliterate Unicode to ASCII in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii, transliteration

How do I transliterate Unicode characters to ASCII in pure Javascript?

```
input:  'Ǐńťęř'
output: 'Inter'
```

I need similar effect as shells `iconv -f UTF-8 -t 'ASCII//TRANSLIT'` but in vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Your Question already has an answer, but this is just for fun: [Fun with Uni!!](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/814000tj/show)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Transliterating to ASCII is more of a compression function than replacing some of the letters with European stuff on them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the answer from [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string) like this:

```
var makeSortString = (function() {
  var translate_re = /[αβγ]/g; // etc.
  var translate = {
    "α": "a", // alpha - a
    "β": "b", // beta -- b
    "γ": "g"  // gamma - g
    // etc.
  };
  return function(s) {
    return ( s.replace(translate_re, function(match) { 
      return translate[match]; 
    }) );
  }
})();
```

You could extend it to include only the characters you want.