# Filter images while typing based on "alt" tag

Tags: javascript, image, search, dynamic, filter

I need to show dinamically only images that contains the text typed in an input field, based on text contained in "alt" attribute.

I need some filter for special chars and case insensitive for typed text, too. Example, when the word "coração" is typed, images with "coracao" must be shown in results, and also ignore the case ("CORAÇÃO" must returns images with "coracao", or "Example" must returns "example"). Remembering, the alt attributes won't contains any special chars.

The code I have is (I don't know javascript, just found in internet)

```
    $("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val === "")
        $('img').show();
    else {
        $('img').hide();
        $('img[alt*=' + val + "]").show();
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you're wanting. Note that this will work in **ES6 ONLY** (which means newer browsers -- probably nothing less than Internet Explorer 11). Special characters are stripped out using `String.Prototype.Normalize()` as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901740/4017749) answer.

```js
$('#myinput').keyup(function() {
  let val = $.trim(this.value);
  val = val.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
  if (val === '') {
    $('img').show();
  } else {
    $('img').hide();
    $('img').each((i, img) => {
      let imgAlt = img.alt.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
      if((imgAlt.toLowerCase()).indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $(img).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myinput">
<img alt="CORAÇÃO">
<img alt="CORACAO">
<img alt="foo">
<img alt="bar">
<img alt="baz">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvLj3ete/), I'll soon send you the filter for the special characters!

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x80" alt="16">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x80" alt="15">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x80" alt="14">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/130x80" alt="13">

<input type="text" id="filter">

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim(this.value);
  if (val === "")
    $('img').show();
  else {
    $('img').hide();
    $('img[alt*=' + val + "]").show();
  }
});
```

UPDATE: The new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvLj3ete/) with the special characters!

Comment: This is exactly the code I have. I need some way to ignore case and special characters. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to remove the special characters, but keeping the related letters.

You could use the string [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method, and then remove the unwanted characters:

```js
function removeDiacritics(str) {
    return str && str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
}

removeDiacritics('Coração'); // Coracao
```

**Update**

To make it work in your code do it something like:

```js
$(function() {
    function removeDiacritics(str) {
        return str && str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
    }

    function normalize(str) {
        return (removeDiacritics(str) || '').trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    $("#myinput").keyup(function() {
        var val = normalize(this.value);

        if (val === "")
            $('img').show();
        else {
            $('img').hide();
            // assuming the alt is already normalized
            $('img[alt*=' + val + "]").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- You can enter words with special characters in the input, like CORAÇÃO -->
<input id="myinput">

<img alt="coracao">
<img alt="construcao">
<img alt="automovel">
<img alt="estacao">
```

You can see both the html and the js code in the snippet above.

Comment: Hello, where I put this in code?
`<input type="text" id="filter">

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim(this.value);
  if (val === "")
    $('img').show();
  else {
    $('img').hide();
    $('img[alt*=' + val + "]").show();
  }
});`

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano The code `<input type="text" id="filter">` should be in your HTML while the code `$("#filter")...` should be in a javascript (js) file (or inside a `script` tag in the HTML). If you use a js file, just include it in your html (`<script src="my-script.js"></script>`).

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano updated the answere with the js code.