# search as unicode angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to search `pokemon` and find all Pokémon results (with accent)

My array:

```
let games = ['The Legend of Zelda', 'Pokémon', 'Chrono Trigger']
```

How I'm doing:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let game of games | filterBy:[]:search">{{game}}</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the [ng-pipes](https://github.com/a8m/ng-pipes) package to use `filterBy`

**TS**

```
public search: string = ''
```

But if I type `pokemon` he don't match with `Pokémon`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan oh, you think?

Comment: Please can you check this link https://gist.github.com/akora/51b2933a2554776d7144#file-remove-diacritics-google-sheet I hope you will find what you want. And I'm sorry I inattentively read your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I managed to solve by doing some tests.
I decided to create a function that returns the value handled by regex.

Follow the result

**TS**

```
public games = ['The Legend of Zelda', 'Pokémon', 'Chrono Trigger']
public gamesCopy = this.games

public search: string = ''

private slug(val) {
  val = val.replace(/[áàãâä]/g, 'a')
  val = val.replace(/[ÁÀÃÂÄ]/g, 'a')
  val = val.replace(/[éèêë]/g, 'e')
  val = val.replace(/[ÉÈÊË]/g, 'e')
  val = val.replace(/[íìîï]/g, 'i')
  val = val.replace(/[ÍÌÎÏ]/g, 'i')
  val = val.replace(/[óòõôö]/g, 'o')
  val = val.replace(/[ÓÒÕÔÖ]/g, 'o')
  val = val.replace(/[úùûü]/g, 'u')
  val = val.replace(/[ÚÙÛÜ]/g, 'u')
  val = val.replace(/[ç]/g, 'c')
  val = val.replace(/[Ç]/g, 'c')
  return val.toLowerCase()
}

public searching(search: string) {
  this.gamesCopy = this.games.filter(res => this.slug(res).indexOf(this.slug(search)) > -1)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" (ngModelChange)="searching($event)">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let game of gamesCopy">{{game}}</li>
</ul>
```

I removed [ng-pipes](https://github.com/a8m/ng-pipes)

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about IE support, you can use the [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="search" (ngModelChange)="onSearchChange($event)">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let game of games | filterBy:[]:search">{{game}}</li>
</ul>

onSearchChange(search: string): void {
  this.search = search.normalize('NFKD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036F]/g, '');
}
```

This will normalize any weird characters you might have.

If you do care about IE, you should find another method from here: [Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)