# Generalizing a replace function to accept parameters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following function.

from here
[Efficiently replace all accented characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string)

```
function test() {
  let aa = 'čǧǩőšűžČǦǨŐŠŰŽ'

  const ccc = wontParse(aa)
  console.log(ccc)

}

var wontParse = (function () {
  let in_chrs   = 'čǧǩőšűžČǦǨŐŠŰŽ',
      out_chrs  = 'cgkosuzCGKOSUZ', 
      chars_rgx = new RegExp('[' + in_chrs + ']', 'g'),
      transl    = {}, i,
      lookup    = function (m) { return transl[m] || m; };

  for (i=0; i<in_chrs.length; i++) {
    transl[ in_chrs[i] ] = out_chrs[i];
  }

  return function (s) { return s.replace(chars_rgx, lookup); }
})();
```

I want to edit the function, so to accept two additional parameters so as to call it like so:

```
function test() {
  let x  = 'čǧǩőšűžČǦǨŐŠŰŽ',
      y  = 'cgkosuzCGKOSUZ';

  let aa = 'čǧǩőšűžČǦǨŐŠŰŽ'

  const ccc = wontParse(aa,x,y)
  console.log(ccc)

}
```

I got this to work

```
var wontParse2 = (in_chrs,out_chrs) => (function () {
  let chars_rgx = new RegExp('[' + in_chrs + ']', 'g'),
      transl    = {}, i,
      lookup    = function (m) { return transl[m] || m; };

  for (i=0; i<in_chrs.length; i++) {
    transl[ in_chrs[i] ] = out_chrs[i];
  }

  return function (s) { return s.replace(chars_rgx, lookup); }
})();
```

So I can call it like this `const ccc = wontParse(x,y)(aa)`

But how to edit the function so it can be called like this? `const ccc = wontParse(aa,x,y)`

I do not understand the function well enough to do so
particularly this

```
transl    = {}, i,
lookup    = function (m) { return transl[m] || m; };
```

and the last `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically just moving the `s` parameter into the original call. Then you just return `s.replace(...)` as you did before. You also don't need to wrap the body in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
var wontParse2 = (s, in_chrs, out_chrs) => {
  let chars_rgx = new RegExp("[" + in_chrs + "]", "g"),
    transl = {},
    i,
    lookup = function (m) {
      return transl[m] || m;
    };

  for (i = 0; i < in_chrs.length; i++) {
    transl[in_chrs[i]] = out_chrs[i];
  }

  return s.replace(chars_rgx, lookup);
};
```

Comment: Thank you that makes  it a bit more understandable